# infinite watcher rootscope errors in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this watcher :

```
  $scope.bool = false;
  $scope.$watch(function(){
    return sessionService.get('computed');
    }, function(){
      if (sessionService.get('computed')) {
        $scope.bool = true;
      } else {
        $scope.bool = false;
      }
  });
```

and this button in the menu.html of this ionic app :

```
<button nav-direction="back" class="button yy" ui-sref="app.result" ui-sref-active="currentNav" ng-show="bool" ng-click="navResult()">
      Board
    </button>
```

and here is the sessionService:

```
.service('sessionService', ['$cookieStore', function ($cookieStore) {
    var localStoreAvailable = typeof (Storage) !== "undefined";
    this.store = function (name, details) {
        if (localStoreAvailable) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(details)) {
                details = null;
            } else if (angular.isObject(details) || angular.isArray(details) || angular.isNumber(+details || details)) {
                details = angular.toJson(details);
            };
            sessionStorage.setItem(name, details);
        } else {
            $cookieStore.put(name, details);
        };
    };

    this.persist = function(name, details) {
        if (localStoreAvailable) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(details)) {
                details = null;
            } else if (angular.isObject(details) || angular.isArray(details) || angular.isNumber(+details || details)) {
                details = angular.toJson(details);
            };
            localStorage.setItem(name, details);
        } else {
            $cookieStore.put(name, details);
        }
    };

    this.get = function (name) {
        if (localStoreAvailable) {
                return getItem(name);
        } else {
                return $cookieStore.get(name);
        }
    };

    this.destroy = function (name) {
        if (localStoreAvailable) {
            localStorage.removeItem(name);
            sessionStorage.removeItem(name);
        } else {
            $cookieStore.remove(name);
        };
    };

    var getItem = function (name) {
        var data;
        var localData = localStorage.getItem(name);
        var sessionData = sessionStorage.getItem(name);

        if (sessionData) {
            data = sessionData;
        } else if (localData) {
            data = localData;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        if (data === '[object Object]') { return null; };
        if (!data.length || data === 'null') { return null; };

        if (data.charAt(0) === "{" || data.charAt(0) === "[" || angular.isNumber(data)) {
            return angular.fromJson(data);
        };

        return data;
    };

    return this;
}])
```

At a certain point, the app creates the variables `computed` and stores it into sessionStorage.

I get an infite cycle error due to the watcher.
Can you help please ?

Comment: You have an infinite digest loop. Sometimes caused by updating X from watcher Y, and having watcher X updating Y. The digest can never be finished.

Comment: ok need to check my code again

Comment: @ThinkingMedia I edited my question

Comment: Can you put in your sessionService?

Comment: @MathewBerg of course here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"At a certain point, the app creates the variables computed and stores it into `sessionStorage.`"

If that's the case, fire an event on `$rootScope`

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('computedChanged');
```

And then in your controller where you had the `$watch`:

```
$scope.$on('computedChanged', function(){
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks Mathew, it works for me. Just a question : Are $rootscope event always available on $scope ?

Comment: If you use $broadcast, it'll hit every child $scope, so yes.